# Rsyslog.conf disable mail.info and/or disable postfix reporting

Tags: postfix, syslog, rsyslog

I have log entries like:

```
Apr  8 10:25:31 monitor postfix/smtpd[3131]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr  8 10:25:31 monitor postfix/smtpd[3131]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr  8 10:25:31 monitor postfix/smtpd[3131]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

every minute or so on a central rsyslogd log monitoring box from all local/remote nodes (Debian Squeeze, Rsyslog 4.6.4, Postfix 2.7.1 both from repos), I've tried to disable info messages in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` by commenting out the line:

```
#mail.info                      -/var/log/mail.info
```

and also adding a line

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none,cron.none,mail.none -/var/log/syslog
```

which I thought would disable all mail logging from Postfix into `/var/log/syslog`, but it doesn't help. I have searched for other `mail.info` `mail.debug` entries and there are none, just one entry like:

```
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
```

which I've commented out too, but then I think that shouldn't cause logging to `/var/log/syslog` anyway, no?

Answer (score 12):

You are using the wrong syntax, you have to use ";" as a delimiter.

This worked for me:

```
*.*;mail.none;mail.error;auth,authpriv.none             -/var/log/syslog
```

You need to restart rsyslog after the changes. Reloading isn't enough.

Comment: In ubuntu 14 the file to edit is `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`

Comment: It seems that `/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart` doesn't restart the service properly in Ubuntu 14.04. You would need to do: `service rsyslog restart` instead.